# Update foreign key Laravel one to many relation eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, laravel-5.5

I have Account model like this:

```
class Account extends Model
 {  
    public function Contact()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('app\Contact');
  }
  public $fillable = ['account_id'];
}
```

and Contact model like this

```
class Contact extends Model

{
    public function Account()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('app\Account');
   }
}
```

and accounts table

- id
- name

and contacts table

- id
- account_id

When I update account I want to update account_id field on contacts table. 
I send contacts related to this account with `contact_array` varaible

My code:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
    $Account = Account::find($id);
    $Account->update($request->all());
    $Account->Contact()->delete(); ###delete all relations
    foreach ($request['contact_array'] as $val){
        $contact=Contact:: find($val);
        $Account->Contact()->save($contact);
    }
}
```

But do not anything and I test this

```
foreach ($request['contact_array'] as $val){
     $test=  DB::table('contacts')
     ->where('id', $val)
     ->update(['account_id' => $Account->id]);
}
```

but does not work.

Comment: are you trying to delete all relations and re-create the relation again??

Comment: @Sohel0415 yes of course

Answer (score 1):

You can use do like this -

```
foreach ($request['contact_array'] as $val){
     $contact=Contact:: find($val);
     $contact->account_id = $Account->id;
     $contact->save();
}
$Account->loadMissing('Contact');
```

Comment: I don't want create new contact  I want only update account_id field

Comment: My code is true. problem is very bullshit. I test it on phpmyadmin with google chrome. and it show me blank but when I use with firefox It show me account_id field. So thanks for your time